# iOS empty popover

Tags: ios, ipad, popover

I am trying to show a picker view in a popover on iPad, but the popover is empty

```
case timezoneSetting: {
        UIViewController *pickerViewController = (setting.type == timeSetting) ?
                [[[TimePickerViewController alloc] initWithSetting:setting] autorelease] :
                [[[TimeZonePickerViewController alloc] initWithSetting:setting] autorelease];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            CGRect frame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            CGRect cellRect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y - tableView.contentOffset.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

            [pickerPopover setContentViewController:[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pickerViewController] autorelease]];
            [pickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:cellRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp) animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:pickerViewController animated:YES];
        }

        break;
    }
```

Comment: please add code of how you are creating and adding the `UIPickerView` to your popover view

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm missing, this is legacy code and I thought initwithRootViewController: pickerViewController was supposed to handle that? So I guess not?

Comment: it might be. you need to check the implementation of `TimePickerViewController` and make sure there is an actual `pickerView` being added

Comment: there is, it works fine on iphone when it just pushes the view controller, but its empty in a popover when on iPad

Comment: you need to verify the frame is set correctly. something like pickerView.frame = self.view.bounds

Comment: i get an error that says "frame is not found on UIViewController" when i try your suggestion above

Comment: [pickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) is a `UIView` so it does have a `frame` property. Please post relevant code so I can help you further.

Comment: Fixed it with `[pickerPopover initWithContentViewController:pickerViewController]` thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

`[pickerPopover initWithContentViewController:pickerViewController]` was what we needed to be calling